# How to justify that if i=j=0 i will have a 0 in the Needleman-Wunsch or Levenchtein distance algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I can't understand why we are setting the D(0,0) to 0 in the alignment matrix when we are running the algorithms for minimum distance like the Levencthein algorithm?

Comment: Please correct occurrences of *Levenshtein* in title and body of your post..

Comment: Please include more details in your post, such as the exact algorithm you’re referring to, and what it is supposed to compute.